# setting up ubuntu server with spoofed mac address

Tags: network-programming, ubuntu-server

I have two computers and one ethernet cable.

The cable is from admin and only one mac address is allowed to have internet connection.

The mac address is set for my main pc.

I want to set up an ubuntu server on my second pc while I am gone.

I already installed the ubuntu server on the second pc but it was unable to automatically configure the network (since it has a wrong mac address).

I am familiar with changing the mac address, but not with setting up the network manually.

**Is there a way to set up the network automatically like it was seen in the setup phase?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to set up the network automatically after the instalation finished, but I have solved my problem by choosing "set network manually" in the installation menu.

Then I retyped all network info from my first pc - I have windows so I looked up ethernet part of ipconfig /all.

After the installation finished I spoofed the mac address and it works!